# Assert validate empty array collection symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, assert

Is there a way to validate and check an array of collection if it is  or not empty. I already tried :

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length( min = 1)
 */
protected $workPlaces;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->workPlaces = new ArrayCollection();

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with the [Count assert](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Count.html#basic-usage)

```
// src/Entity/Participant.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Participant
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Count(
     *      min = 1,
     *      max = 5,
     *      minMessage = "You must specify at least one email",
     *      maxMessage = "You cannot specify more than {{ limit }} emails"
     * )
     */
    protected $emails = [];
}
```

> Validates that a given collection’s (i.e. an array or an object that
> implements Countable) element count is between some minimum and
> maximum value.

Do not specify `max` if you do not need it.